# Chrome randomly inverted colors across my devices. How to reset?

Tags: google-chrome

Out of the blue, chrome inverted all of my colors across all of my devices. In Incognito mode, there are no issues. How do I reset this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going to Settings > Advanced > Reset Settings.

Turns out I had an extension called "Hacker Vision" that was randomly enabled.